# Why does windows azure In-Role caching requires a storage account?

Tags: caching, azure

I was wondering why widows azure In-Role caching service requires an azure storage account.
My understanding is that the cache cluster is stored on the role's instances so why does it need the storage account?

If the storage is needed for persistency, then could i choose not to use it and have a non-persistent cache service?

I couldn't find clear answers for these questions.

What i need is to have the data saved across several role instances in-memory.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From [`About In-Role Cache for Azure Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh914161.aspx) on MSDN (last paragraph under `Cache Cluster` section):

> Each cache cluster maintains shared information about the **cluster's
>   runtime state in Azure storage**. During development, you can use the
>   Azure storage emulator. Deployed roles must specify a valid Azure
>   storage account. In Visual Studio, you can specify the appropriate
>   storage account on the Caching tab of the role properties.

Comment: yeah i already read that but its obscure. I was hoping for some more detailed information or a place where i can read it.